# Show certain sums go to zero in order to use a weak law of large numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am working on a problem where I need to show two limits in order to be able to apply a weak law of large numbers. Here is what I know:

> $p_k=\frac{1}{2^kk(k+1)}, k=1,2,\dots$ and $p_0=1-\sum_{k\geq 1} p_k$. Now let $X_1, X_2,\dots$ be i.i.d. with $P(X_n=-1)=p_0$ and $P(X_n=2^k -1)=p_k$ for $k\geq 1$.
>
> Let $S_n=X_1 + \dots + X_n$, let $b_n=n/\log_2(n),$ let $\overline{X_{n,k}}=X_k 1_{\{|X_k|\leq b_n\}}$, and finally let $a_n= \sum_{k=1}^n E(\overline{X_{n,k}}).$

What I would like to show is the following:

> I) $b_n^{-2}\sum_{k=1}^n E \left(\overline{X_{n,k}}^2\right)\rightarrow 0$,
>
> II) $\frac{a_n}{b_n}\rightarrow -1.$

Here is the work I have so far for I):
$$
b_n^{-2}\sum_{k=1}^n E \left(\overline{X_{n,k}}^2\right)=b_n^{-2}\sum_{k=1}^n E \left(X_1 1_{\{|X_1|\leq b_n\}}^2\right)=b_n^{-2}nE \left(X_1 1_{\{|X_1|\leq b_n\}}^2\right)
$$
$$
\leq b_n^{-2}n\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P\left(X_1 1_{\{|X_1|\leq b_n\}}^2 > k\right)=b_n^{-2}n\sum_{0\leq k \leq b_n}P\left(X_1^2 > k\right)
$$
$$
\leq b_n^{-2}n\left[2+\sum_{2\leq k \leq b_n} P\left( X_1^2 >k \right)\right].
$$

This is where I get stuck.

Here is the work I have so far for II):
$$
a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n E\left(\overline{X_{n,k}} \right)=nE \left(X_1 1_{\{|X_1|\leq b_n\}}\right).
$$
So I can bound $a_n$ between 
$$
n\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P\left(X_1 1_{\{|X_1|\leq b_n\}}\geq k\right)\leq a_n \geq n\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P\left(X_1 1_{\{|X_1|\leq b_n\}}>k \right).
$$
Then I get stuck here.

I am really in need of some help on this problem. Thank you.

> UPDATE:
>   I used a different approach to show I) and succeeded. If instead of bounding the expectation from above like I did you actually calculate it you are able to show that it goes to $0$.
>
> Now this is what I have so far in my attempt to show II)
>   $$
> -1\leq a_n=nE \left(X_1 1_{\{|X_1|\leq b_n\}}\right)=n\left(-p_0 + \sum_{1\leq k\leq b_n}(2^k -1)\frac{1}{2^k k (k+1)}\right).
> $$
>   Now I somehow want to either show that this goes to $-1$ or it is bounded above by something that goes to $-1$.

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^n E \left(\overline{X_k}^2\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n E \left(X_1^2 1_{\{|X_1|\leq b_{\color{red}{\bf k}}\}}\right)\ne\sum_{k=1}^n E \left(X_1^2 1_{\{|X_1|\leq b_{\color{red}{\bf n}}\}}\right)=nE \left(X_1^2 1_{\{|X_1|\leq b_n\}}\right)$$

Comment: @Did Sorry, I think I wrote the notation incorrectly. I have edited it to fix that mistake.